# How can I use the data in my Adapter to show it in my GridView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I'm a beginner in android development, I created a gridView and wrote an adapter for it, and I use this grid view in a fragment! I get the data from the server in my fragment which is 2 string array, how can i use the data in my adapter to show in my gridview?
thanks in advance!

```
String[] gridViewPicture;
String[] gridViewText;
//some codes to get my data from server    
gridViewText[i] =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString();
gridViewPicture[i] =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("picture").toString();
```

this is my adapter for GridView:

```
  class GridItem{
    int imageSource;
    String Text;
    GridItem(int imageSource,String text)
    {
        this.imageSource=imageSource;
        this.Text=text;
     }
    }

    public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<GridItem> list;
    Context context;
    public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;

        list = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
        Resources contextResources = context.getResources();


        String[] foodText= {"text1","text2","text3"}; //this is the text that should change and get it from server

        int[] image={R.drawable.first_slider_1min,R.drawable.first_slider_2min,R.drawable.first_slider_3min};//this is the image that should change and get it from server
        for(int i=0;i<foodText.length;i++)
        {
            GridItem gridItem= new GridItem(image[i],foodText[i]);
            list.add(gridItem);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }




    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView myfoodImage;
        TextView myfoodText;
        ViewHolder(View view){

            myfoodImage=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.GridLayoutPhoto);
            myfoodText=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.GridLayoutName);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        GridItem myGridItem = list.get(position);
        holder.myfoodText.setText(myGridItem.Text);
        holder.myfoodImage.setImageResource(myGridItem.imageSource);


        return row;
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you post code? We need to see it to be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Gridview adapter like this and pass the data to it from the fragment

```
   String[] foodText ;
   int[] image ;
    public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context , String[] foodText ,int[] image){
            this.context=context;
            this.foodText=foodText;
            this.image=image;

            list = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
            Resources contextResources = context.getResources();

            for(int i=0;i<foodText.length;i++)
            {
                GridItem gridItem= new GridItem(image[i],foodText[i]);
                list.add(gridItem);
            }

        }
```

Here you need to pass the data to adapter in this way

```
  MyGridViewAdapter adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(ActivityContext ,gridViewText , gridViewPicture);
   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In other way before setting the data to adapter it self you can prepare your GridItem data and then directly pass it to adapter.

Like this

```
String[] gridViewPicture;
String[] gridViewText;
//some codes to get my data from server    
gridViewText[i] =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString();
gridViewPicture[i] =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("picture").toString();

ArrayList<GridItem> list = new ArrayList<GridItem>;


int[] image={R.drawable.first_slider_1min,R.drawable.first_slider_2min,R.drawable.first_slider_3min};//this is the image that should change and get it from server
        for(int i=0;i<foodText.length;i++)
        {
            GridItem gridItem= new GridItem(gridViewPicture[i],gridViewText[i]);
            list.add(gridItem);
        }
```

then your adapter should be look like this

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<GridItem> list;
    Context context;
    public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GridItem> list){
        this.context=context;
        this.list =list;


    }
```

In second case you can directly pass the data to Adapter like this.

```
MyGridViewAdapter adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(ActivityContext ,list  );
  listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```